# How do I center these footer a's?

Tags: html, css

If you go to http://www.leapfm.com and scroll down to the footer you'll see that the links are on the right bottom hand side.

How can I put em' in the center?

Please use Firebug or inspect element for easy access to the code.

Comment: You mean "Contact Us, FAQ..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'll start top down from the div class="footer", you'll need to change or add these css properties:

```
.footer {
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   width: auto;
}
```

The li for the links inside footer:

```
.footer li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Then the a tags inside the above li tags:

```
.footer li a {
   display: inline-block;
   float: none;
}
```

Comment: Ah this is closest to solving it as the links are now centered. Although they are vertical instead of horizontal.

Comment: You mean horizontally centred and not vertical, right? The common way is to set a padding. By removing the <br> at the top of the .footer div then setting padding: 30px 0 0; roughly, it'll centre the content.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the li-elements properly in a ul, and set `margin: 0 auto` on it.

Instead of using li-elements as separators, you could use `li + li:before { content: "|"; }`

Comment: I'd use `li + li:before` so you get the separator only *between* elements. http://jsfiddle.net/HtLEf/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the CSS float:right for the class declaration.

```
.footer a {
    float: right; //Remove this
    display: block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to enclose the `<li>` tag with `<ul>`

and after that add this css :

```
.footer {
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
}
.footer ul {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
.footer li {
   float: left;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:right;` from `.footer a` and enclose you are `li` tags with `ul`

```
<div class="footer">
    <ul>
          <li><a href="/songs/new">Submit |</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="/faq">FAQ | </a></li> 
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should enclose each of these LI's in a UL or OL.

Contrary to what the others have pointed out, you dont need to give the UL/OL a margin of 0 auto because it will already take up the entire space it has. Or give a display:block to the footer and text align. So when you set a text-align:center to the li; they will magically go in the center of the element. *No need to center the parent element*(the ul).

Also, if you want to do things the right way, get rid of the br tag and use margin or padding to space your way around your layout.

So; all you need to add to your code is this:

```
ul{
text-align:center;
}

ul li{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Sorry to put this in an answer. I would have rather be a comment to the top answer. I dont have enough rep for that. Not glory hunting!

Hope this helps